# how to NSException get localized NSLocalizedDescription

Tags: nserror, nsexception

I got an Exception

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1fd68a20 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://mac-mini.local/~user/restcon/auth?username=&password=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://mac-mini.local/~user/restcon/auth?username=&password=, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1fd25730 "The request timed out."}

How can I get the NSLocalizedDescription?

If I 'po 0x1fd68a20' in debugger, I can get the NSDictionary I want.
But the [exception userInfo] returns me nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your exception is in an object of type NSException, try

```
NSString *errorDescription = [exception.error.userInfo valueForKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey].
```

Comment: Thank you, I almost forgot this question. actually, you are correct. the returned object is not NSException, it's a NSError, I access the wrong variable.

Comment: Are you getting the localised string for "The request timed out" NSURLErrorDomain error ?